# I am trying to install path_provider package in pubspec.yaml but keep it failing

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Because nacoss_app depends on path_provider >=2.0.0-nullsafety which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of lower SDK version. Try to upgrade it.
Go to 'Tools' -> Flutter -> 'Flutter Upgrade'

or

`flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).